# Pronunciation of 'z' at the beginning of a word

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

It appears that the pronunciation of 'z' at the beginning of a word is controlled by the subsequent consonant(s), that is, [ts] when followed by the aspirated [f], [k], [p], [t], and then [dz] when followed by the voiced [v], [g], [b], [d] and liquids [l], [m], [n], [r]. However, how do I understand the exceptions: [dz] for zafferano, zaffiro, zefiro, zeta, zippare, zitella, zotico, and [ts] for zangola, zanna, zimbello, zingaro? It does not appear to be related to open/closed vowels nor to accented/unaccented. Are these simply exceptions, along the line of the great argument on z/zz in the middle of the word (other posting)?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! This is a very interesting question (but, I guess, a very difficult one).

Comment: Note that, according to *Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronuncia*, some of these words admit both pronunciations: [zitella](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=648&r=15819), [zangola](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=220&r=64325),  [zimbello](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=575&r=10586), [zingaro](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=605&r=3265).

Comment: I suspect this is another thing that varies widely on a regional basis

Comment: As an Italian, I must admit I didn't know about the rule about the pronunciation of “z” according to the following consonant (after a vowel, I presume). Where can I find more about it?

Comment: @DaG:  I have a book called *Manuale di dizione e pronuncia*, by Ughetta Lanari (I found it at an Italian airport), which gives this and other rules. But  it's a quite short book, so there aren't many details. "The following consonant" refers to the first consonant of the second syllable.

Comment: @Charo Ughetta Lanari used to work as a radio announcer, very appreciated for her wonderful elocution.

Comment: @egreg:  It's an interesting book with comes with two CDs so you can hear the pronunciation. But it's extremely difficult to me to remember all these rules, I mean, rules of the kind of the ones that appear in the question. And I would say it's also quite difficult to find an Italian who really follows this "standard pronunciation".

Comment: I'm an opera singer who helps other opera singers pronounce "correctly" when they sing the lyric repertory. So the "rules" to which I was referring are the standard patterns of how the tongue moves in the mouth as one sings words: the forward high aspiration of [tʃ] positioned parallel to [f-k-p-t], etc.  I can teach young singers to pronounce a beginning 'z' [ts] when the following syllable begins with an [f] and that contributes to the legato line due to parallel placement. However, a common beginner's song from the canzoni napoletane Is "Santa Lucia" with the word "zefiro".

Comment: A lot of song lyrics are antiquated (poetic) vocabulary. I am asking if "zefiro" is one of those words which can be pronounced either way? Most online sources give [dz], but then perhaps it came straight from Greek (one source puts its etymology together with zero). It's confusing when my only example from a song doesn't match most of the other patterns. Is there some commonality to the exceptions or not? Thanks so much for your engagement on this. 
P.S. yes, I'm dealing with the translated Italian lyrics, not the original Napoletano lyrics.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @Suzanne. I wonder whether this is just an empirical, rule-of-the-thumb rule, or has some deeper background reason like, say, [vowel harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_harmony) in some languages. As an Italian, I confess that, if asked about such a rule, I'd have either answered “Look up the correct pronunciation in a dictionary” or mumbled something about etymology.

Comment: According to *Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronuncia*, *z* in [zefiro](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=395&r=382) is pronounced voiced. You can check pronunciations of these words [here](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/ricerca.aspx).

Comment: I'm afraid there's no hard-and-fast rule. Etymology has its role. And regional accents too! Where I live nobody would speak about their /'tsio/, but about their /'dzio/, when referring to their uncle. Notwithstanding the etymology of *zingaro* from German *zigeuner*, everybody here would say /'dzingaro/.